# Ripple page transtion flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code that makes a ripple effect appear for a page transition, it works almost perfectly, but when I place it in a column, for example, the effect appears behind the other widgets, or behind the appbar as well.

If anyone knows a package that does this, or help me.

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    rippleController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
    scaleController =
    AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 1))
      ..addStatusListener((status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          scaleController.reverse();
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              PageTransition(
                  type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeftWithFade, child: SuccessPage(identificado: true)));
        }
      });
    rippleAnimation =
    Tween<double>(begin: 90.0, end: 90.0).animate(rippleController)
      ..addStatusListener((status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          rippleController.reverse();
        } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
          rippleController.forward();
        }
      });
    scaleAnimation =
        Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 30.0).animate(scaleController);

    rippleController.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    rippleController.dispose();
    scaleController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: rippleAnimation,
        builder: (context, child) => Container(
          width: rippleAnimation.value,
          height: rippleAnimation.value,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              scaleController.forward();
            },
            child: AnimatedBuilder(
                animation: scaleAnimation,
                builder: (context, child) => Transform.scale(scale: scaleAnimation.value,
                  child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.blue),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                        ],
                      ),
                  ),)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```